# put the defined name in a reportviewer PDF in asp.net c #

Tags: c#, asp.net, reportviewer

I have this fragment of code that what it does is generate me a 
***PDF or also EXCEL.*** 
how do I define to the moneto to visualize or to download gives me with that name.
example 
***EXCEL.excel or PDF.pdf*** 
I am looking for the way to define a fixed name example 
***rodo.pdf or rodo.excel***

```
public ActionResult print(ParametrosGeneral param, string id, FormCollection TipoReporte)
{

string Format = "pdf";
//  string Format = "excel";


LocalReport lr = new LocalReport();
string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Reportes"), "Libro.rdlc");

if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
{
    lr.ReportPath = path;
}
else
{
    return View("Index");
}

ReportDataSource rd = new ReportDataSource("DSLibro", LibroVenta(4, 2018).Tables[0]);    //here returns my query with the meters for 4 and 2018 that I send
lr.DataSources.Add(rd);

string reportType = Format;
string mineType;
string encoding;
string fileNameExtension;

string deviceInfo =
    "<DeviceInfo>" +
    "<OutputFormat>" + Format + "</OutputFormat>" +
    "<PageWidth>11in</PageWidth>" +
    "<PageHeight>8.5in</PageHeight>" +
    "<MarginTop>0,787402in</MarginTop>" +
    "<MarginLeft>0,787402in</MarginLeft>" +
    "<MarginRight>0,787402in</MarginRight>" +
    "<MarginBottom>0,787402in</MarginBottom>" +
    "</DeviceInfo>";

Warning[] warnings;
string[] streams;
byte[] renderedBytes;

renderedBytes = lr.Render(
        reportType,
        deviceInfo,
        out mineType,
        out encoding,
        out fileNameExtension,
        out streams,
        out warnings);

return File(renderedBytes, mineType);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try along these lines. The file name will be `somepdf.pdf`

```
var cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
{
    FileName = "somepdf.pdf",
    Inline = true
};
Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());

return File(bytes, "application/pdf");
```

Comment: hello, hello ??

Comment: @RodrigoRodriguez Where do you seem to miss it. Add the content disposition to your response header just before your `return File(renderedBytes, mineType);`